# VS2015 c++: some c++ static libraries references appear with warnings (yellow triangles)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I use project references in my c++ vs2015 projects. It works well except for a few projects which display yellow triangles for the references projects.

I can't find any warning messages, no tooltip for the yellow triangles. The "add reference" dialog doesn't show the project as referenced. So if I need to remove a dependency, I have to manually edit the project file.

Any idea on what the issue is or where I can find warning messages?

**PS**:
If you open a C++ project in vs2015, and you right click on "References" and select "Add Reference", a dialog pops up, allowing to reference static or dynamic libraries.

This allows automatic linking with the referenced libraries and also set the build order accordingly to the dependencies.

If you now expand "References", you will see now the referenced libraries with at the left a grey icon

If you re-open the "Add Reference" dialog, the referenced libraries appear with a checked checkbox

In my case, for some executables (not for static libraries), the grey icon appear with an overlay of the shape of a yellow triangle. I guess it's a warning, is it? I can get any information about the issue

Now, automatic linking and build order still work as expected. But when I re-open the "Add Reference" dialog, the referenced libraries are no more checked.

Comment: Maybe a picture would help remind me what you're talking about?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add a picture as it is blocked by my company proxy. I will try to be more accurate in the description